# How to build a list of libraries with make?

Tags: c, makefile

I have this makefile:

```
LIBS = \
lib1 \
lib2
etc...

libs : $(LIBS)

$(LIBS) :

    @if [ -f lib/${@}/makefile ]; then cd lib/${@}/; $(MAKE); fi
```

I need it to switch into the directory for each library and build it. For some reason, only the first library in $LIBS (i.e. lib1) is built.

Is $@ the correct variable to use here?

Thanks!

Comment: Copied and pasted your exact makefile above (minus the `etc...` line) and with `lib/lib1/makefile` and `lib/lib2/makefile` files it worked just fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `lib/${@}/makefile` doesn't exist, but `lib/${@}/Makefile` does? `make` works fine with either.

In general, you shouldn't test whether the makefile exists; if it doesn't exist that should be an error: Either the directory is not a library directory, or `$(LIBS)` is being used for several things, which means it should be refactored.